Duplicate NuGet prop/targets related Imports After Migrating to SDK-Style Projects in .NET
I've recently migrated around 100+ legacy .NET Framework projects to SDK-style projects. In the legacy projects, we used to manually import NuGet-related .props and .targets like this:
<Import Project="$(PkgBond_CSharp)\build\Bond.CSharp.props" Condition="Exists('$(PkgBond_CSharp)\build\Bond.CSharp.props')" />
<Import Project="$(PkgBond_CSharp)\build\Bond.CSharp.targets" Condition="Exists('$(PkgBond_CSharp)\build\Bond.CSharp.targets')" />
Now, after migration, I'm encountering a lot of duplicate imports for these .props and .targets files. My understanding is that SDK-style projects should automatically handle these imports when I use the  tag to reference NuGet packages.
My questions are:
Do I still need to explicitly import NuGet-related .props and .targets files in SDK-style projects?
If they are required for certain packages, how should I handle these imports when adding new packages? Should I manually add the import statements, or will the .NET SDK handle this automatically?
I want to ensure I'm following best practices and avoid issues with duplicate imports in the future.
